# How to scale secondary axis that has positive and negative values to a primary axis with only positive values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a bar chart with a trend line, but the problem I have is the transformation of scales to make the charts match, as I have positive and negative data.
The transformation I made shows the negative values below the bars[This is what I have achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnuZv.png) but I want the line to be above the bars as seen in the last graph[I am looking for this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8By1.png).

I attach the data and the code

```
#Data
YEAR<- seq(2005,2024, by =1)
PIA <- c(294632872,318970713,295673727,308391873,308706714 ,323206154, 409271206,409217000,
         475475074,496270114,517171633  ,624824866 , 616674888 , 708032291 , 708184529 , 649368974,
         649368974,879366475,879744600,1084148245)
percentage_increase <- c(-9.38109456, 8.26039567, -7.30380096 , 4.30141228  ,0.10209121 , 4.69683338, 26.62853134,
                     -0.01324452 , 16.19142753  ,4.37352895,  4.21172229, 20.81576524, -1.30436198, 14.81451649,
                     0.02150156, -8.30511718 , 0.00000000, 35.41861564 , 0.04299971, 23.23443020)

Congreso_11 <- data.frame(YEAR,PIA,percentage_increase)

df_line <- data.frame(YEAR = Congreso_11$YEAR,
                      value =Congreso_11$percentage_increase*30500000)
#Graphic
ggplot(Congreso_11,aes(YEAR,PIA))+
  geom_col(width = 0.8)+
  geom_point(data =df_line, aes(x =AÑO,y =value),color = "blue", size = 4)+
  geom_line(data =df_line, aes(x =AÑO,y =value),color = "red", size = 2)
```

I tried multiplying smaller and larger numbers to the variable "percentage_increase" without getting the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had was that you didn't transform your negative percentage values to positive before multiplying them. Here's an approach that scales your right y-axis values correctly, and creates nicely aligned axis breaks. You don't need to create a separate df_line object, you can just add the right y-axis values to Congreso_11.

Some modifications may be required regarding the definition of the breaks if data are different to the example data and have different ranges. This example creates breaks at 10% intervals but you can customise it to suit.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Data
YEAR<- seq(2005,2024, by =1)
PIA <- c(294632872,318970713,295673727,308391873,308706714 ,323206154, 409271206,409217000,
         475475074,496270114,517171633  ,624824866 , 616674888 , 708032291 , 708184529 , 649368974,
         649368974,879366475,879744600,1084148245)
percentage_increase <- c(-9.38109456, 8.26039567, -7.30380096 , 4.30141228  ,0.10209121 , 4.69683338, 26.62853134,
                         -0.01324452 , 16.19142753  ,4.37352895,  4.21172229, 20.81576524, -1.30436198, 14.81451649,
                         0.02150156, -8.30511718 , 0.00000000, 35.41861564 , 0.04299971, 23.23443020)

Congreso_11 <- data.frame(YEAR,PIA,percentage_increase)

# Function to return exponent for rounding min and max to nearest log10()
exp_for_rnd <- function(x) {
  y <- as.character(x)
  y <- sub("\\..*$", "", y)
  z <- sub("^[1-9]0*", "", y)
  count <- nchar(z)
  return(count)
}

# Get rounded extent values for left y-axis
l.y.min <- 0
l.y.max <- max(Congreso_11$PIA)
n <- exp_for_rnd(l.y.max)
l.y.max <- l.y.max + (10^n - l.y.max %% 10^n)

# Get rounded extent values for right y-axis
r.y.min <- abs(min(Congreso_11$percentage_increase))
n <- exp_for_rnd(r.y.min)
r.y.min <- (r.y.min + (10^n - r.y.min %% 10^n)) * -1 # * -1 required only if min < 0

r.y.max <- abs(max(Congreso_11$percentage_increase))
n <- exp_for_rnd(r.y.max)
r.y.max <- (r.y.max + (10^n - r.y.max %% 10^n))

# Function to scale values
axis_scaled <- function(x) { (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) * l.y.max}

# Scale values
sv <- axis_scaled(c(r.y.min, Congreso_11$percentage_increase, r.y.max))
sv <- sv[2:(length(sv)-1)]

# Add sv to Congreso_11
Congreso_11$value <- sv

# Create labels for right y-axis and breaks for left y-axis
r.y.labels <- seq(r.y.min, r.y.max, 10)
l.y.breaks <- seq(l.y.min, l.y.max, length.out = length(r.y.labels))

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = Congreso_11, aes(YEAR, PIA),
           width = 0.8,
           fill = "grey60") +
  geom_point(data = Congreso_11, aes(x = YEAR, y = value),
             color = "blue", 
             size = 4) +
  geom_line(data = Congreso_11, 
            aes(x = YEAR, y = value),
            color = "red", 
            linewidth = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous("PIA",
                     breaks = l.y.breaks,
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .,
                                         breaks = l.y.breaks, 
                                         labels = r.y.labels,
                                         name = "Percentage Increase"))
```

[image: result]

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I've corrected it, again thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To get a secondary axis you need of course add one using the `sec.axis=` argument of `scale_y_continuous`. Additionally, to get the correct or desired scale for the secondary axis requires to apply the inverse transformation on the values using the `trans=` argument, which in your case is `trans = ~ .x / 30500000`

```r
library(ggplot2)

Congreso_11$value <- 30500000 * Congreso_11$percentage_increase

ggplot(Congreso_11, aes(YEAR, PIA)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8) +
  geom_point(
    aes(x = YEAR, y = value),
    color = "blue", size = 4
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(x = YEAR, y = value),
    color = "red", size = 2
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = ~.x / 30500000
    )
  )
```

[image]